# The point within the range of rectangle

Tags: geometry, language-agnostic

In easy English can someone please explain to me this line of code.

```
public bool IsAt(Point2D pt)
    {
        return (pt.X > Width && pt.X < Width + X && pt.Y > Height && pt.Y < Height + Y);
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to understand much english, just [Euclidian geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry).

Answer (score 1):

Return true if the coordinates pt.X, pt.Y are outside a rectangle with width: WIDTH and height: HEIGHT with an origin at coordinates X, Y.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Width` and `Height` are actually the width and the height of a defined rectangle, then I'd go with the class `System.Drawing.Rectangle` and use the method `Contains()` to check if a point is in a rectangle.

Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.contains?view=net-6.0#system-drawing-rectangle-contains(system-drawing-point)

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect the next logic:

```
pt.X > X && pt.X < X + Width && pt.Y > Y && pt.Y < Y + Height
```

assuming `X,Y` is bottom left corner (when OY is up).

In your code variable naming is too strange.